# Calculating the throughput in multithreading code

Tags: java, multithreading, throughput

I am doing `bench marking` on some of my client code. Now I am trying to find out how to calculate the throughput from my `Multithreading` code-

I am running my program with `20 threads`. And each thread is going to run for `15 minutes`, so all the `20 threads will run for 15 minutes`.

Below is my code-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

try {

        // create thread pool with given size
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);

        // queue some tasks
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long endTime = startTime + (15 * 60 * 1000);

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            service.submit(new CassandraReadTask(endTime, columnFamilyList));
        }

        service.shutdown();
        service.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.warn("Threw a Exception in" + CNAME + e);
    }
}
```

Below is my class that implements `Runnable interface`-

```
class CassandraReadTask implements Runnable {

    public void run() {

        try {

            while (System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTime) {

                double randomNumber = random.nextDouble() * 100.0;

                final String id = generateRandomId(random);

                ICassandraClientDao clientDao = ClientFactory.getInstance().getDao(clientName);

                clientDao.getAttributes(id, columnsList, columnFamily);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            }
    }

}
```

And from the above code, I am generating some random id and that id I am using it to pass to my `getAttributes` dao method.

So from my understanding. Total `throughput` will be-

```
total number of request/ total duration the program was run
```

So, in my case, it will be-

```
total number of id's I have generated/15 minutes
```

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing it fine as long as you properly count up (maybe using a shared `AtomicInteger`?) all of the requests done by the different threads.

However, I would switch your code around a bit and submit 100,000 (or something) random-ids and then time how long it takes for your threads to handle all of those ids.  That's a more realistic test since it will better show your task submission overhead.

Then you just put a `startTimeMillis` and calculate the difference from the end to the start and then calculate 100,000 (or whatever your number was) divided by the diff to give you your average iteration/millis.

Something like:

```
long startTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
int numIterations = 100000;
for (int i = 0; i < numIterations; i++) {
    double randomNumber = random.nextDouble() * 100.0;
    final String id = generateRandomId(random);
    service.submit(new CassandraReadTask(id, columnFamilyList));
}
service.shutdown();
service.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);
long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimeMillis;
System.out.println("Average time per iteration is " + (numIterations / diff));
```

Then it's easy to play around with the number of threads and the number of iterations to maximize your throughput.

Comment: that just measures the time to create the tasks, but not actually running them, right?

Comment: Yes that's what I am also thinking. Correct me Gray, If I am wrong.

Comment: Ooops.  Right.  I forgot to copy down the `shutdown()` and `awaitTermination(...)`.  Thanks @RalfH.

Comment: Yes, I am using `AtomicInteger` to count it.

Answer (score 0):

that seems to be correct, but how do you count? You could use Callables instead of Runnables to return the numer of IDs generated. Then you would get all your Futures after shuttung down the Executor to sum it up.

Comment: The id, I am generating is `String id`, so it will look like, `1` or `100` or `2000`. So everytime it is generating anything, I am increasing the static counter by `1`. I haven't shown the code for the counter in my above example. But that's the way I am doing it. And then I can use that counter to calculate the throughput. Is that sounds right?

Comment: OK, if you have some place to count, then you don't need to use futures. But that counter must be thread-safe, which means another point of synchronization and there fore less throughput than without counting. Better use Gray's approach and submit a known number of jobs and take their execution time.

Comment: Would you provide a Full Working example?